# What is the purpose of creating a struct with only one field

Tags: c, struct

On the project in my company I saw a couple of times people creating a struct that contains only one element.
the latest one is added, in this example ipAddr is another struct( a good explanation to the case when ipAddr is an array is given by 'Frerich Raabe' but unfortunately thats not the case here)

```
typedef struct
{
  ipAddr ip;
} Record;
```

I guess if the code is changing and in its beginning this makes sense since more fields can be easily added and the code can be easily manipulated to support the new fields, but this is a project started a long time ago written according to a design so I dont think its the issue here.

Why would one create a struct of one field then?

Comment: Did you consider asking your coworker? Communication is important in software development.

Comment: Two obvious reasons are readability and portability.

Comment: @Philipp of course, no one knows who wrote it exactly and when (I guess I can find the name but it will be a witch hunt to track him). none of my coworkers couldn't explain it neither.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I cant see why this makes the code more portable. also it terms of readability wouldn't it be easier to typedef the name to the wanted name?

Comment: @Anton.P Sometimes it is very hard to follow someone else's thought process. The available documentation for design and architecture of the application should be your next best friend. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A common reason for a struct with just one field is that the single field is an array, and you'd like to be able to define functions returning such array values. Consider e.g.

```
typedef unsigned char ipAddr[4];

void f(ipAddr ip);         /* OK */
ipAddr g(void);            /* Compiler barfs: cannot return array. */
```

This can be resolved by introducing a `struct` with a single member of type `ipAddr`:

```
typedef unsigned char ipAddr[4];

typedef struct {
    ipAddr ip;
} Record;

void f(Record ip);         /* OK */
Record g(void);            /* Also OK: structs can be returned by value. */
```

However, even passing arrays to functions is problematic: you don't actually pass the array, you pass a pointer (the type "decays" into a pointer). Imagine `f` declared above would need to create a copy of the given IP address:

```
typedef unsignd char ipAddr[4];

void f(ipAddr ip) {
    ipAddr *a = malloc(sizeof(ip));
    /* ... */
}
```

This only happens to work with 32bit builds because the size of a pointer is the same (4 bytes) as the size of an array of four `unsigned char` values. A 64bit build (or a differently sized array) would exhibit a bug, either allocating too much or too little memory. This happens because inside `f`, `ip` is of type `unsigned char *`, i.e.a pointer. A `struct` helps with this, since it doesn't decay.

Comment: @that's a really good usecase, thank you very much for this I didn't think about it, unfortunately in my case the ipAddr is a struct itself(edited the question to add this). If the only reason is a possible adding of fields later this is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: Now I have found out that there is something hidden inside the parameter passing, its allows because of a greater thing: you can assign one struct to another with the `=` sign, this is super usefull if those structs contains an array of fixed size!! it copies the array!!

Answer (score 8):

I can think of a couple reasons:

1. In case more fields may be needed later.  This is somewhat common.
2. To deliberately make the outer type incompatible with the inner type.

For an example of the second, imagine this:

```
typedef struct
{
    char postal_code[12];
} Destination;
```

In this case, the Destination is fully specified by the postal code, yet this will let us define functions like this:

```
int deliver(const char* message, const Destination* to);
```

This way, no user can inadvertently call the function with the two arguments reversed, which they could easily do if they were both plain strings.

Comment: Thank you for the interesting thought, regarding the later added fields I thought about it but as I said its an old code and I am wondering if its time to delete this redundancy. my question is about the second thought, is it worthy and common to add a struct and have another level in the hierarchy just to protect from this mistakes?

Comment: @Anton.P: Is it (point #2) common?  No, I wouldn't say it's common at all.  It might be more popular with people familiar with C++, where that sort of thing is more common (`Destination` in my example would be a class with methods like `validate()`).  Should you do it?  Only if you feel it's necessary.  It'll probably annoy some C purists if you do it for reason #2.